# Unable to run yum command on RHEL 7

Tags: linux, redhat, yum

I have a new Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3, I am trying to install Ambari Server on this machine by following the steps in the link

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.0.0/bk_Installing_HDP_AMB/content/_download_the_ambari_repo_lnx7.html

I am able to run the first step i.e

```
wget -nv http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos7/2.x/updates/2.1.0/ambari.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/ambari.repo
```

But when I am executing the next steps `yum repolist` or `yum install ambari-server` I am getting the following error.

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager


rhn-plugin: RPM error.  The message was:
Could not determine what version of Red Hat Linux you are running.
If you get this error, try running 

        rpm --rebuilddb
```

I ran the above command but it did not solve my problem. I tried to search for the answer but I did not find anything on the internet.

Can anyone identify this problem?

Comment: Please note that SO is about *programming* problems. As indicated by the close requests, there are better places to ask such kind of questions. Besides superuser.com, you could also try http://unix.stackexchange.com/ for example.

Comment: Thank you, I will post my question there.